# Typescript specialized overloads defined on a subclass or interface

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to make the following work without having to define an implementation in the subclass which simply calls the superclass or unnecessarily repeats the non-specialized signature?

```
class Emitter {
    on(name: 'one', handler: (value: number) => void): void;
    on(name: string, handler: (...args: any[]) => void): void;
    on(name: string, handler: (...args: any[]) => void): void { 
        // do stuff
    }
}


class Subclass extends Emitter {
    on(name: 'two', handler: (value: string) => void): void;
    on(name: string, handler: (...args: any[]) => void): void;
    // error no implementation specified
}


interface IEmitter {
    on(name: 'one', handler: (value: number) => void): void;
    on(name: string, handler: (...args: any[]) => void): void;
}


interface ISubclass extends IEmitter {
    on(name: 'two', handler: (value: string) => void): void;
    // error overload not assignable to non specialized
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function overloads only get combined if they are call signatures on an object type. The easiest fix (for the interface case) is to separate out the function type into its own interface and extend that:

```
interface EmitterEvent {
    (name: 'one', handler: (value: number) => void): void;
    (name: string, handler: (...args: any[]) => void): void;
}

interface SubclassEmitterEvent extends EmitterEvent {
    (name: 'two', handler: (value: string) => void): void;
}

interface IEmitter {
    on: EmitterEvent;
}

interface ISubclass extends IEmitter {
    on: SubclassEmitterEvent;
}

var x: ISubclass;
x.on('one', n => n.toFixed()); // n: number
x.on('two', s => s.substr(0)); // s: string
var y: IEmitter;
y.on('two', a => a); // a: any
```

The equivalent version in the class case takes some work (assuming you care about the function going on the prototype -- if not, just use a function expression as an initializer for `on` instead):

```
class Emitter {
    on: EmitterEvent;
}
module Emitter {
    Emitter.prototype.on = function(name: string, handler: any) {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan! This approach is workable, but is very different from declaring method overloads on interfaces (ala addEventListener). Is there any chance that future versions of TypesScript will allow method overloads on classes to reuse the base class implementation (provided it's compatible)?

Comment: Unlikely, since that would either require some new syntax or a breaking change.

Comment: The version where the function goes on the prototype has a drawback, the function can't call other private functions from the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that with TS 1.5 the module trick (which is now called a namespace) won't work, as it complains about 'this'.

Below a working approach which I'm using:

```
interface EventEmitterOn {
    (event: string, listener: () => void);
}

interface FooEventEmitterOn extends EventEmitterOn {
    (event: 'dependency', listener: (dep: string[]) => void);
}

class EventEmitter {
    on: EventEmitterOn;
}

EventEmitter.prototype.on = function(event, listener) {
    // implementation
}

class Foo extends EventEmitter {
    on: FooEventEmitterOn;
}

var foo = new Foo
// error
foo.on('dependency', function(dep: number) {})
// ok
foo.on('dependency', function(dep: string[]) {})
```

Answer (score 0):

For a less verbose solution, check out [ee-ts](https://github.com/aleclarson/ee-ts). It provides a typed `EventEmitter` class with support for:

- strict event names (think `string` unions for the `type` in `emit(type, ...args)`)
- type-checked `emit` and `on` calls (never again emit the wrong type or expect the wrong types in a listener)

```
import { EventEmitter as EE } from 'ee-ts'

type User = { name: string }

// All possible events must be explicitly defined as methods here.
// The return type can be non-void because the `emit` method returns the last non-void value.
// The return type can never be required, because `void` is implicitly added to every event.
interface Events {
  login(user: User): void
  logout(): string
}

// Make your subclass generic to let users add their own events.
class App<T = {}> extends EE<T & Events> {
  /* ... */
}

let app = new App()

// The type of `user` is inferred.
app.on('login', user => {
  console.log(user.name) // user.name is string
})

// Invalid argument types are caught.
app.one('login', (invalid: boolean) => {}) // [ts] Type 'User' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

// Invalid return values are caught.
app.one('logout', () => true) // [ts] Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string | void'.

// Unknown event names are caught.
app.emit('invalid') // [ts] Argument of type '"invalid"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"login" | "logout"'.
```