# TypeScript: specialized signatures for EventEmitter subclass events

Tags: events, typescript, overloading, typescript1.8

I have a base class `EventEmitter`, which has the `on` method to bind handlers on specific events:

```js
class EventEmitter {
    on(event: string, handler: Function) {
        /* add handler internally */
    }

    protected emit(event: string, ...args) {
        /* call all handlers listening on event */
    }
}
```

Now I have various subclasses, which can emit different events with different arguments. I'd like to "declare" which events can be emitted by that specific class:

```js
class MyClass extends EventEmitter {
    on(event: 'event1', handler: (arg1: number) => void): void;
    on(event: 'event2', handler: (arg1: string, arg2: number) => void): void;
}
```

So my sub class may emit the events `event1` and `event2`, but this does not seem to be the right way to specify. TypeScript (tsc 1.8) is compaining:

```
error TS2415: Class 'MyClass' incorrectly extends base class 'EventEmitter'.
  Types of property 'on' are incompatible.
Type '(event: "event1", handler: (arg1: number) => void) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: string, handler: Function) => void'.
  Type '(event: "event1", handler: (arg1: number) => void) => void' provides no match for the signature '(event: string, handler: Function): void'
error TS2382: Specialized overload signature is not assignable to any non-specialized signature.
error TS2391: Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration.
```

So, what is the intended way to specify the events my class can emit?

EDIT: I've found the name of what I was looking for: [Specialized Signatures](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v1.8.7/doc/spec.md#3924-specialized-signatures). However, it seems to be meant for interfaces only, and not for new TypeScript code.

Now I've found [anothother question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703577/typescript-specialized-overloads-defined-on-a-subclass-or-interface) about the same issue from 2015, however the solution there does not look quite right. So, are there other ways to do it in TypeScript today?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52339294/2228559) should help you.

Answer (score 2):

> what is the intended way to specify the events my class can emit?

Instead of using a single *event* stream that contains *all the types* its easier to have a separate *event* stream for *each* type.

This is a concept I call `TypedEvent`. One example project that uses it is http://alm.tools/

Implementation : https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/blob/55a8eb0f8ee411a506572abce92085235658b980/src/common/events.ts#L20-L72

Here is an example usage : https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/blob/55a8eb0f8ee411a506572abce92085235658b980/src/server/lang/errorsCache.ts#L10

```
export let errorsUpdated = new TypedEvent<ErrorsUpdate>();
// emit: 
errorsUpdated.emit({} /* this will be type checked */);
// consume:
errorsUpdated.on((x)=>null); // x has the correct inferred type
```

Comment: This could be an approach, however it seems to be a different style. I'd like to adapt the existing style of node.js (`instance.on(eventName, handler)`) and HTML DOM (`element.addEventListener(eventName, handler)`).

Comment: The standard node.js style was not authored with static type checking in mind. It relies on documentation rather than code time analysis and does not model as nicely in typescript.

Comment: Could you show me an example with your approach using my example classes and events? If I understand it correctly, I should define an event subclass for each possible events. My modules are not external and my classes share the same namespace. Two classes may emit 'event1' / `Event1Event` but have different properties, depending on the class emitting it.