# How does one annotate EventEmitter in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to annotate events and event handlers for a typical EventEmitter in TypeScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript: specialized signatures for EventEmitter subclass events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35735548/typescript-specialized-signatures-for-eventemitter-subclass-events)

Comment: A quick [web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=eventemitter+typescript) didn't find me any advice on annotating a traditional Node EventEmitter implementation but did find lots of alternate code patterns and libraries, e.g., [this](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/typed-event.html) and the thread I'm targeting as a duplicate.