# Declaring events in a TypeScript class which extends EventEmitter

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a class extends `EventEmitter` that can emit event `hello`. How can I declare the `on` method with specific event name and listener signature?

```
class MyClass extends events.EventEmitter {

  emitHello(name: string): void {
    this.emit('hello', name);
  }

  // compile error on below line
  on(event: 'hello', listener: (name: string) => void): this;
}
```

Comment: What's the error? And seems like your `on` method is lacking a body.

Comment: As @NitzanTomer said, either your `on` method is lacking a body, or you want to declare the `event` parameter as an other type than `'hello'`.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52339294/2228559) should help you.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Most usable way of doing this, is to use `declare`:

```
declare interface MyClass {
    on(event: 'hello', listener: (name: string) => void): this;
    on(event: string, listener: Function): this;
}

class MyClass extends events.EventEmitter {
    emitHello(name: string): void {
        this.emit('hello', name);
    }
}
```

Note that if you are **exporting** your class, **both** the interface and class have to be declared with the `export` keyword.

Comment: just make **Update 1** the answer because the other way is more problematic.

Answer (score 72):

to extend @SergeyK's answer, with this you can get type-checking and completion on both `emit` and `on` functions without repeating event types.

1. Define event listener signatures for each event type:

```
interface MyClassEvents {
  'add': (el: string, wasNew: boolean) => void;
  'delete': (changedCount: number) => void;
}
```

2. Declare interface which constructs types for `MyClass`, based on EventListeners (`MyClassEvents`) function signature:

```
declare interface MyClass {
  on<U extends keyof MyClassEvents>(
    event: U, listener: MyClassEvents[U]
  ): this;

  emit<U extends keyof MyClassEvents>(
    event: U, ...args: Parameters<MyClassEvents[U]>
  ): boolean;
}
```

3. Simply define you class extending `EventEmitter`:

```
class MyClass extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

---

Now you will get type checking for `on` and `emit` functions:

[image]

[image]

Unfortunately you will get completion and type-checking only on those two functions (unless you define more functions inside MyClass interface).

To get more generic solution, you can use [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiny-typed-emitter).
**note:** it adds no runtime overhead.

```
import { TypedEmitter } from 'tiny-typed-emitter';

interface MyClassEvents {
  'add': (el: string, wasNew: boolean) => void;
  'delete': (changedCount: number) => void;
}

class MyClass extends TypedEmitter<MyClassEvents> {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

Comment: That package is absolutely fantastic. *By far* the most user-friendly solution I've seen so far. Thank you!

Comment: @MaxTruxa Glad you found it useful :)

Answer (score 12):

Here's what I was able to figure out. Overriding the default function with a generic!

```
interface IEmissions {
  connect: () => void
  test: (property: string) => void
}

class MyClass extends events.EventEmitter {
  private _untypedOn = this.on
  private _untypedEmit = this.emit
  public on = <K extends keyof IEmissions>(event: K, listener: IEmissions[K]): this => this._untypedOn(event, listener)
  public emit = <K extends keyof IEmissions>(event: K, ...args: Parameters<IEmissions[K]>): boolean => this._untypedEmit(event, ...args)

  this.emit('test', 'Testing') // This will be typed for you!
}

// Example:
const inst = new MyClass()
inst.on('test', info => console.log(info)) // This will be typed!
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. This gives the ability to override the functions while still enforcing the typing.

Comment: Very elegant! I have managed to even simplify this by not having to store original methods as members by simply invoking `super`. This worked for me in TS 4.1.3: ```public on<K extends keyof MyEvents>(e: K, listener: MyEvents[K]): this { return super.on(e, listener); }```

Comment: super nice version for Typescript code, using the `super` duplicate the line with on, off, once, emit.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [typed event emitter package](https://github.com/Morglod/tsee) for this.

eg:

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'tsee';

const events = new EventEmitter<{
    foo: (a: number, b: string) => void,
}>();

// foo's arguments is fully type checked
events.emit('foo', 123, 'hello world');
```

This package also provide interfaces & some utils.

Comment: This is awesome, I like you package!

Answer (score 5):

I really liked @Binier's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61609010/8107589) and especially the generic solution offered by [tiny-typed-emitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiny-typed-emitter). As an alternative, I wrote up this pure-typescript version:

```js
type EmittedEvents = Record<string | symbol, (...args: any) => any>;

export declare interface TypedEventEmitter<Events extends EmittedEvents> {
  on<E extends keyof Events>(
    event: E, listener: Events[E]
  ): this;

  emit<E extends keyof Events>(
    event: E, ...args: Parameters<Events[E]>
  ): boolean;
}

export class TypedEventEmitter<Events extends EmittedEvents> extends EventEmitter {}
```

It's used similarly:

```js
type MessageSocketEvents = {
  'message': (json: object) => void;
  'close': () => void;
};

export class MessageSocket extends TypedEventEmitter<MessageSocketEvents> {
  ...
}
```

Comment: This is quite nice.